# ассемблер:преобразовать входную последовательность символов к нижнему регистру

Tags: ассемблер, символы

надо считать из одного файла, преобразовать его последовательность  к нижнему регистру, а затем преобразованную последовательность записать в другой файл. Не знаю как преобразовать последовательность. Приведите пожалуйста пример кода по преобразованию последовательности!
Код программы (что есть):

```
page 60,180
TITLE  Lab7.asm      ;

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATASG       SEGMENT  PARA  'Data'
filename    db  'c:\L7_punkt12.txt',0 
filename2   db 'g:\L7_punkt131.txt',0
filename3   db ?
filenmae4   db 'L7_punkt133.txt',0

filename5   db  'c:\L7_punkt12.txt',1 
value       db 1
handle      dw  ?
F1L7        db 'c:\F1_L7.txt',0
F2L7        db 'c:\F2_L7.txt',1    
F3L7        db 'c:\F3_L7.txt',1
DATASG        ENDS
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODESG       SEGMENT  PARA  'Code'
BEGIN           PROC          Preobrazovanie
ASSUME  SS: STACKSG, CS:CODESG, DS:DATASG, ES:NOTHING
PUSH       DS
SUB        AX,AX
PUSH       AX  
;reading
mov ah, 03Fh        
mov bx, F1l7        
mov cx, recsize     
mov dx, offset buffer   
int 21h     
jc  Error                 


;writitng
mov ah, 40Fh        
mov bx, buffer      
mov cx, recsize     
mov dx, offset F2L7 
mov ah, 03Eh        
int 21h         
jc  Error            

BEGIN           ENDP
CODESG       ENDS
END    BEGIN
```

Comment: Если символ между 41h и 5Ah прибавить к нему 20h, для английского алфавита. Символы других языков в зависимости от кодировки

Comment: А как это в коде выглядеть будет ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если символ находится в `al`, то что-то типа

```
  cmp   al, 41H
  jl    low
  cmp   al, 5AH
  jg    low
  or    al, 20H
low:
```